# Plot a figure and exit but leave figure window open

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have created a script (`plot.py`) that plots a Matplotlib figure. I would like the script to plot the figure and then exit immediately but still leave the figure open. I know I can do this using the ampersand in a terminal window:

```
$ plot.py &
```

but I would like to avoid typing the ampersand each time and do this by forking a new process instead, I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing

def main():
    p = Process(target=showFigure)
    p.start()
    p.join()

def showFigure():
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    print ('Starting: {} {}'.format(p.name, p.pid))
    x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
    y = np.sin(x)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.title('Simple test')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But this does not work. I also tried to remove `p.join()` and to use `daemon=True`..

Comment: The process owns the GUI objects, if it exits, the windows must close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is solution that works on Linux:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import os

def main():
    pid=os.fork()
    if pid==0:
        showFigure()

def showFigure():
    x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
    y = np.sin(x)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.title('Simple test')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```